# Combining quadratic and linear matrix terms into a quadratic term

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given

$$ C = AFA^T + A\bar{F} $$

where $A = [A_1 A_2]$, $F = \begin{bmatrix}
F_1 & F_2 \\ 
F_2^T & F_3 
\end{bmatrix}$, $\bar{F} = 2 \begin{bmatrix}
\bar{F}_1 \\ 
\bar{F}_2
\end{bmatrix}$ such that $A_i \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times k}, F_i = F_i^T \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times k}, \bar{F}_i \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times n}$ and further $F_i, C = C^T  \succeq 0$.

Is it possible to represent $C \succeq 0$ in the following compact-quadratic form:

$$ C = A_M F_M A_M^T $$

for some $A_M$ with $F_M = F_M^T \succeq 0$?

Comment: Why are you using F for two different matrices?

Comment: Do you have a requirement that you do not want to "mix" $A$ and $F$ terms? Otherwise that is trivially true; every $C \succeq 0$ can be written as $BB^T$ for some $B$.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni hi - yes, I need to keep the $A, F$ terms separate. he closest i came across was a DT Lyapunov eqn here en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_equation but of course I have an ¯ sitting in the second term so am not sure ... i just needed a way to combine the second piece into the first one so was thinking if the second-linear term could be re-written as a quadratic in  somehow via sq. root etc but couldn't arrive at a firm concl. also, $k \leq n$.

Comment: Then I would suggest that you edit your requirements in the question. Your form for $C$ can only produce terms of the form $(A_M)_{ij}(F_M)_{jk}(A_M)_{lk}$, so if you want to have a term not in this form you will have to include some nonzero constants inside $A$...

Comment: thank you - i am totally open to any additions to the $A, F, \bar{F}$ matrices once I can collapse these into the quadratic expression. Would appreciate any assistance with this.